# when bootstrap date picker date select some action call in ember js controller

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, bootstrap-datepicker

I am new to ember, developing Filtering by date functionality using ember js.

handle bars:

```
<div class="input-group date" data-behavior="ActiveRock.filterDatePicker" data-date-before-field="#filter_end_date">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="filter_start_date" {{action filterPortfolios}}/>
   <span class="input-group-addon">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
   </span>
</div>
```

Behaviour:

```
$ ->
  ActiveRock.datePicker = (el) ->
  el.datepicker(
  format: 'yyyy/mm/dd'
  autoclose: true
    ).on('show', (e) ->
  $('.datepicker').css('z-index', '1151')
  true
    ).on('hide', (e) ->
    logic
    return false
  true
)
```

controller action: filterPortfolios

included bootstrap datepicker

but it is not working, please suggest any solution.

Thanks, 
Prasad.

Comment: looks like you're using a JQuery plugin for a daterangepicker. Could you post more relevant code? views, controller, etc?

Comment: You better use a component for datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

In behavior I written like taht

```
$(function() {
  return ExamplePicker.filterDatePicker = function(el) {
    return el.datepicker({
      format: 'yyyy/mm/dd',
      autoclose: true
    }).on('changeDate', function(e) {
      var controller;
      controller = App.__container__.lookup("controller:<controller_name>");
      controller.send("<action_name>");
      return true;
    });
  };
});
```